# jquery live problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys, i got a problem here, any 1 can help?^^

in this program i tried to use live(for ajax issue)

```
<div id="rpt1" class="test"></div>
<div id="rpt2" class="test"></div>
<div id="rpt3" class="test"></div>
<div id="rpt4" class="test"></div>
<div id="rpt5" class="test"></div>

$('.test').live('click',test2);
```

after that i tried to unbind or die one of the handler

```
$('#rpt1').die('click');
```

if i use

```
 $('.test').die('click');
```

i will die all ..... which is the last thing i wanna do.
i but the event still binded.
i wondering how to solve this.. tried for several hour edi ..
thx ^^

may b i put the live code here.
i got lot of these div

{$lang.report}

{$lang.re.spam}

and then the live at here
   $(".report").live('click',function(){

```
                            if($(this).next(".report_type").is(':visible')){
                                    $(this).next(".report_type").hide();
                            }else{
                                    $(this).next(".report_type").show()
                            }
                                    return false;
                            });
```

function report_comment(category,comment_id,report_type)
           { blah blah blah
            $('#report'+comment_id).die('click');
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the callback function as the second argument
`$('.test').die('click',test2);`

see: http://api.jquery.com/die/#die2

**Edit**:

I misunderstood your question.

try this `$('#rpt1').removeClass('test');` to remove the live event from one of the divs

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/TEZhb/

Comment: i'm assuming in my answer that the test class is only for the events and not for styling.

Comment: this way can work, but my mate ask me to do it without delete the class, this is what make me headache, it for styling also ...i think of make a dummy class to achieve this....

Comment: the alternative is to not use `live` and instead attach regular click events AFTER the content has been loaded via ajax. You can then remove click events from individual divs using `unbind`

Answer (score 0):

try passing handler to die

> `$('.test').die('click',test2);`

Comment: but inside test2 what should i put??
function test2(){
$('#rpt1').die('click');

}
it look like same to me

Comment: i tried both solution,it seem cannot, anyway thx for ur helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     $('.test').live('click',function(){
        var $id = $("#" + $(this).attr('id'));

        if($id.next().is(':visible')){
                $id.die('click');
                $(id).next().hide();
        } else { 
                $id.die('click');
                $id.next().show();
        }
     });
```

Comment: i think this cannot work,if i click once, then other div cannot b click,anyway thx for ur helps ^^

Comment: but i already add the real code on my question, u can take a look ^^ thx

Comment: @Leon pls clarify your html and jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing a very important peace of information from [.die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/)

> Note: Up to jQuery 1.4.4, in order for .die() to function correctly, the selector used with it must match exactly the selector initially used with .live().

every example they give the click and die is applied to the same selector

Comment: ya, what i tried to do is wan to use different selector.i notice that, and i got the problem of different selector, but in my case i need different selector

Comment: so is not possible to do that?

Comment: @Leon It seems that way to me though I'm not 100% certain some like @Nick Craver may know  ?